# cookie config issue when switching between https and http

Tags: servlets, cookies, jetty, session-cookies, web.xml

Am using Jetty 9.2.25 which has Servlet 3.1. I have below cookie configuration in my web.xml

```
<session-config>
<cookie-config>
<http-only>true</http-only>
<secure>false</secure>
</cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

When I set this secure flag as true, it's working. But when I set it as false as shown above and access https site, the secure flag is getting modified to true and I am not able to access http site. I don't understand how is this happening?
Is this the default behaviour?
I tried to check the Servlet release notes, but there's no such update.

Any idea regarding this behaviour?

How can I make the secure as false when I access https?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Jetty 9.2.x is EOL (End of Life).](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/jetty-announce/msg00116.html)

In Jetty 9.4.x (current supported / stable releases of Jetty), you would configure your `SessionHandler` to not have secure requests on by default to achieve the behavior you want.

```java
SessionHandler.setSecureRequestOnly(false);
```

Note: this feature is not available in Jetty 9.2.x